# sql: legality of including ungrouped columns in group by statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, if I do:

```
CREATE TABLE fraction (
  id Int,
  tag Int,
  num Int,
  den Int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (1,1,3,4);
INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (2,1,5,6);
INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (3,2,3,8);
INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (4,2,5,7);
INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (5,1,10,13);
INSERT INTO fraction VALUES (6,2,5,7);

SELECT fraction.tag, max(1.0 * fraction.num / fraction.den)
FROM fraction
GROUP BY fraction.tag;
```

I will get the result:

```
1|0.833333333333333
2|0.714285714285714
```

Then, if I issue:

```
SELECT fraction.tag, max(1.0 * fraction.num / fraction.den),
  fraction.num, fraction.den
FROM fraction
GROUP BY fraction.tag;
```

I will get the result:

```
1|0.833333333333333|5|6
2|0.714285714285714|5|7
```

The latter is what I would expect, but it seems like a happy accident more than anything predictable or reliable.  For example, were the aggregate function `sum` instead of `min`, some type of "rider" column wouldn't make sense.

In a current project that I'm doing, I'm using a table joined to itself to simulate the latter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fraction_a.tag, fraction_a.high,
  fraction_b.num, fraction_b.den
FROM
  (SELECT fraction.tag, max(1.0 * fraction.num / fraction.den) AS high
    FROM fraction
    GROUP BY fraction.tag)
  AS fraction_a JOIN
  (SELECT fraction.tag, fraction.num, fraction.den
    FROM fraction)
  AS fraction_b
  ON fraction_a.tag = fraction_b.tag
    AND fraction_a.high = 1.0 * fraction_b.num / fraction_b.den;
```

yielding

```
1|0.833333333333333|5|6
2|0.714285714285714|5|7
```

But I find that syntax ugly, impractical and unmaintainable.

As I'll be porting my project between several dialects of SQL, I need a solution that is reliable in all dialects. So, if I have to bite the bullet and use the ugly syntax I will, but I'd prefer using the cleaner one.

Answer (score 1):

Including non-aggregated columns in your `SELECT` clause that don't appear in your `GROUP BY` clause is non-portable and will likely cause errors / unexpected results. The syntax you're using is not *cleaner* - it is plain wrong and happens to work on SQLite. It won't work on Oracle (causing a syntax error), it won't work as expected on MySQL (where it will return random values from the group), and it likely won't work on other RDBMS.

The most straightforward way to implement this would be to use a windowing function - but since you need to support SQLite, that's out of the question.

Please note that your second approach (the "ugly" query) will return multiple rows per tag if you happen to have several maxima. This might or might not be what you want.

So bite the bullet and use something like your *ugly* approach - it's portable and will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using GROUP BY, the database has to create a single output row from (possibly) multiple input rows.

Columns mentioned in the GROUP BY clause have the same value for all rows in the group, so this is the output value to be used.

Columns with some aggregate function use that to compute the output value.

However, other columns are a problem, because there might be *different* values in the group.
The SQL standard forbids this.
MySQL forgets to check for this error, and gives some random row's value for the output.
SQLite allows this for compatibility with MySQL.

Since version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html), when you're using MIN or MAX, SQLite guarantees that the other columns will come from the record that has the minimum/maximum value.